# Receiving "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" error when using dataframe in apply function

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I for the life of me can't figure out how to get rid of this error! I'm attempting to see if two different data frames share two columns with the same row (e.g. if both data frames have 'Jacksonville' under column 'City' and 'Florida' under column 'State). I'm trying to run:

```
hpricesold = convert_housing_data_to_quarters()
hprices = hpricesold.copy()
hprices = hprices.reset_index(inplace=False)

def is_uni(df):
    if df in get_list_of_university_towns():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

hprices['Is_Uni'] = hprices.apply(is_uni, axis=1)
```

and the two defs being called:

```
def convert_housing_data_to_quarters():
    #create
    hd = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv')
    hd['State'] = hd['State'].map(states)
    hd = hd.set_index(["State", "RegionName"])
    hd = hd.drop(hd.loc[:, '1996-04':'1999-12'], inplace = False, axis = 1)


    hd = hd.loc[:, '2000-01':'2016-08']
    #finds the average value for each quarter
    hd = hd.groupby(np.arange(len(hd.columns))//3, axis=1).mean()

    #now to name the stupid thing...
    rec = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls', header = [4])
    rec = rec.drop([0,1], axis=0)
    start = rec[rec["Unnamed: 4"] =="2000q1"].index.values.astype(int)[0]

    rec = rec.loc[start:]

    rec = rec.reset_index()
    rec = rec.drop(['index', 'Unnamed: 0', 'GDP in billions of current dollars',
           'GDP in billions of chained 2009 dollars', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 7'], axis = 1)
    rec = rec.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 4' : 'Year', 
                                'GDP in billions of current dollars.1' : 'GDP (bil current)', 
                                'GDP in billions of chained 2009 dollars.1' : 'GDP (bil chained 2009)'})
    rec = rec.append({'Year' : '2016q3'}, ignore_index = True)


    for col in hd.columns:
        hd = hd.rename(columns = {hd.columns[col] : rec.loc[col, 'Year']})





def get_list_of_university_towns():
    #utowns = pd.read_table('university_towns.txt', header=None)
    #utowns = utowns.rename(columns = {0: 'Info'})

    lst = []
    state = ''
    regname = ''

    with open('university_towns.txt') as utowns:
        for line in utowns:
            if line.find("[edit]") != -1:
                location = line.find("[edit]")
                state = line[:location]
                #print (line[:location])

            elif line.find(" (") != -1:
                location = line.find(" (")
                regname = line[:location]
                #print (line[:location])
                lst.append([state, regname])
            #if line.find(":") != -1:
            #    location = line.find(":")
            #    regname = line[:location+1]
            #    lst.append([state, regname])
            else:
                regname = line[:-1]
                #print (regname)
                lst.append([state, regname])

    utowns = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['State', 'RegionName'])
    return utowns
```

I have a feeling that the source of my error is in how I manipulate my dataframe in convert_housing_data_to_quarters(), but I'm getting a little lost in the code. I feel as though it makes sense that each column type is a Series, but how would I then make it immutable so that I can pass this function?

Comment: Posting the error traceback would help someone identify where exactly in the code went wrong, I would to guess the error is happening because you are trying to use a `series` object as  a key in a dictionary, keys need to be hashable.

Answer (score 1):

Note line `hprices['Is_Uni'] = hprices.apply(is_uni, axis=1)` in your code.
It applies `is_uni` function to each row from *hprices* (because you passed *axis=1*).

And now look at the starting row of this function: `def is_uni(df):`.

It means that *df* is actually the **whole row**.

The next line contains `if df in get_list_of_university_towns():`,
so you attempt to check this whole row, whether it is in a list of university towns
(and just this is probably the source of error).

I see here 2 points to correct:

1. Instead of *df* (the whole row), put here only the column containing the city name.
2. After *in*, instead of all the DataFrame returned by this function,
   put only column containing univesity cities.

Another remark: It is a bad practice to call a function generating a whole DataFrame
in a loop, returning the same result each time.

Rather get this DataFrame once, before this loop, save it in a variable,
and pass to this function as a parameter.

And the last remark: Don't use *df* variable name in places where its content
is actually something other than a *DataFrame*. In this case it is a row
from a *DataFrame*, so you can change this name to just *row*
and the code will be much more readable.